# jQuery how to count elements that are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a manual search functionality that displays the results as the user types. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rtq4jfuq/1/

Here is the HTML

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
<input style='width: 300px;' placeholder='search' id='search'>
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='names'>
        <td>Bob</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='names'>
        <td>Ted</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='names'>
        <td>Steve</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='names'>
        <td>Sven</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='names'>
        <td>Magnus</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#search").keyup(function(){ 

        var query = $(this).val(); 

        $(".names").each(function(){ 
             var n = $(this).children("td").html(); 

            if (n.toUpperCase().includes(query.toUpperCase())) { 
                $(this).css("display", ""); 
            } 
            else { 
                $(this).css("display", "none"); 
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

I want to display a message once there are no rows displayed but how do I check if there are no rows displayed?

Comment: Already tryed $(element).is(":visible")  or $(element).css('display') === 'none' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `:visible` filter so see if you've hidden all results:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").keyup(function() {
    var query = $(this).val();
    $(".names").each(function() {
      var n = $(this).children("td").html();

      if (n.toUpperCase().includes(query.toUpperCase())) {
        $(this).css("display", "");
      } else {
        $(this).css("display", "none");

        // Check to see if all elements have been hidden
        if (!$(".names:visible").length) {
          // All element hidden, do something here
          alert("no results");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

FYI - your code can be greatly simplified. This is a quick and dirty example - I'm sure that there's room for further improvement:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").keyup(function() {
    var query = $(this).val();
    var matches = $(".names").filter(function() {
      return $(this).children("td").html().toUpperCase().includes(query.toUpperCase())
    }).show();

    $(".names").not($(matches)).hide();

    if (!$(".names:visible").length) {
      $("#myTable").append("<tr class='noRecords'><td>No records found</td></tr>");
    } else {
      $(".noRecords").remove();
    }
  });
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2rkwvcu/6/).

Comment: Yes I modified some of the parts since this code is just an example. Thank you, it works now!

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you that instead of adding/removing an inline CSS add/remove a class with display none, so you can find how much elements has that class and compare it againist of how much cells you have, if number matches you will know that is not displaying any cell